# C# Casting with conversion operators

Tags: c#, casting, implicit-conversion

I have a custom implementation of the string class. I added custom conversion operators between string and the class, and the casting is working normally. But, if I first cast the custom object to System.Object and then to string it says: "Unable to cast the type 'MyString' to type 'System.String'". Why is that? How can I enable it...

```
class MyString
{
    public string S {get; set;}

    public MyString(string s)
    {
        this.S = s;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyString s)
    {
        return s.S;
    }
    public static implicit operator MyString(string s)
    {
        return new MyString(s);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyString ms = new MyString("a");
        string s = ms;
        object o = ms;
        string s1 = (string)o; // <-- this throws the exception!
    }
}
```

Comment: that is an explicit cast.  you dont have an explicit operator

Comment: explicit casts work if implicit cast is defined.

Answer (score 6):

Conversions like this have to be determined at *compile-time* - whereas in your final line, the compile-time type of `o` is just `object`, so the compiler doesn't "know" about your conversion as an option.

It's hard to know the best solution to your problem other than just saying "don't do that" - if you use `dynamic` instead of `object` (and you're using C# 4, of course) then it'll work - but personally I would just try *not* to rely on user-defined conversions like this. They make the codebase very hard to understand, IMO.

Anyone reading an expression `(string) o` where `o` is just `object` would *expect* it to be a simple cast, i.e. one which would fail if `o` didn't actually refer to a string (or was a null reference). Trying to find ways of confounding that expectation is a bad idea, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I'd override `ToString` in your class. And then use `o.ToString()` instead of `(string)o`.